# Can movement be constrained to an Axis in Kicad Footprint editor?

Tags: kicad

In many CAD tools there is usually a hotkey or modifier to constrain movement to an axis, or 30/56/60/90 degree angles.

Is there a key to constrain movement in this way in the KiCad footprint editor? 
My use case is to move the Footprint courtyard clear of the pins for a component.

Answer (score 2):

The `Ctrl` key works as the constrain key after selecting the point to move.  On Linux, nightly build, this constrains to 0-45-90 degrees.

You will need to set the View canvas to OpenGL or Cairo.

**Edit for Version 6.0:**

Constraining movement is now a state that is set rather than a modifier key.  You can set/unset the state by using the hotkey combination `Shift + Space`

Comment: Hmm - thanks for answering so quickly. I tried that (before and after). I'm on the Windows build - V4.0.5. I've tried it on a label, moving an edge, placing a polyline - and none seem to do it.

Comment: Hmm...Check that you are in either Cairo or OpenGL canvas.  The legacy doesn't have this feature that I can tell.  Also, it only works for lines/edges.  Moving text is unconstrained as far as I can tell.

Comment: Interesting - in OpenGL/Cairo - when I place lines- CTRL sets them to routing 0/45/90. It doesn't effect dragging labels or lines, however - another feature is that in OpenGL and Cairo - it is far more "sticky" on the original alignment - so dragging in only one axis works.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to work in KiCAD 6 anymore.

Comment: @jpa I've updated the answer for v6

Comment: @Seth Wow, thanks a lot - I didn't find that info anywhere else :)